# Maximized windows become maximized behind launcher

Tags: 22.04, launcher, wayland, maximized

[image: a screenshot depicting the below problem]

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, I have encountered a problem related to maximizing windows. Occasionally, and with no triggers I've been able to observe, maximized windows will change their position and size to become additionally maximized, extending behind the launcher. Un-maximizing and then re-maximizing the windows fixes the issue. I am not sure how to obtain any sort of logging or information about when or why this is happening.

Comment: The bug still exists in 23.04. I tried to report it now as a bug, but I was defeated by the launchpad login process.

Comment: this typically happened to me when coming out of a suspend state.